# Подмена enterTransition во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation

Для навигации использую Navigation Component. Имеется 3 фрагмента.  A -> B <- C . Во фрагмент B можно прийти и с A и с С. Хочу подменять во фрагменте B enterTransition в зависимости от того с A пришел человек или с C. Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. Ведь объявить enterTransition можно только в onCreate фрагмента.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions

Comment: Дело в том, что я хочу использовать Transition API.

Comment: решение не глядя на ваши нужды - сделать какой нибудь флаг./мод/энам/как угодно называйте смысл от этого не меняется -  по нему определять что происходит и подсовывать варианты.  В общей практике довольно распостраненное решение. Навигацию вынести куда то , ей передавать мод и все что еще нужно, и там уже пусть решает какая анимация и прочая лабуда будет запедаливаться. обычно как то так